# php, MySql subquery from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a MySql query to produce results based on following:

```
 Table Permissions

user_id     blog_id
=========================
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           2
3           1


Table Blog

id        name
=========================
1         First Blog
2         Second Blog
3         Third Blog
4         Fourth Blog
```

I need to select all the records from Blog table and display it based on logged in user id like:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id];
```

Table Permissions contains access for each user allowed to view results from blog table.

So something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM Blog WHERE id IN()"
```

but I'm not sure how to access permission table to use it in IN().

So for example if user with id 1 is logged in, this user should be able to see Blogs with matching id's 1,2 and 3.

Comment: [A visual explanation of sql joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either a join, or an in() subquery.

```
select b.* from blogs b
inner join permissions p
on b.id=p.blog_id
where p.user_id=...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Blog INNER JOIN Permissions ON Permissions.blog_id = Blog.id
```

This show all users.

Working code here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa3e9/14

You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM Blog INNER JOIN Permissions ON Permissions.blog_id = Blog.id 
WHERE Permissions.user_id = 'user_id number'
```

To get a specific user.